# PHP array_merge_recursive function with empty values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I have below two arrays and used the array_merge_recursive function as I have multidimensional arrays but when one of the key from the first array has a blank value and same key has an array in another array, then after array_merge_recursive function it add "0" key to that key.

e.g.

```
$a = array("id"=>"0", "test-for-draft_FirstName"=>"testtt","test-for-draft_subform1"=>"");
$b = array("test-for-draft_subform1"=>array("test-for-draft_subform10"=>array("subform-1_FileField_60"=>array("name"=>"abcd")),"test-for-draft_subform11"=>array("subform-1_FileField_60"=>array("name"=>"abcdef"))), "test-for-draft_FileFieldTest1"=>array("name"=>"test"));
$extra_jform_data = array_merge_recursive($a,$b);
echo "<pre>";print_r($extra_jform_data);
```

& result is

```
Array
(
    [id] => 0
    [test-for-draft_FirstName] => testtt
    [test-for-draft_subform1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [test-for-draft_subform10] => Array
                (
                    [subform-1_FileField_60] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => abcd
                        )
                )

            [test-for-draft_subform11] => Array
                (
                    [subform-1_FileField_60] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => abcdef
                        )
                )
        )

    [test-for-draft_FileFieldTest1] => Array
        (
            [name] => test
        )
)
```

So, it adds [0] key for `[test-for-draft_subform1]` array. I don't want this. Is there anything another PHP array function to avoid this situation.

Comment: Your $b array specifies that test-for-draft_subform1 contains an array, you don't specify a key, so it becomes 0.
var_dump($b) and you will see what I mean.

The array_merge_recursive is working as expected.

Comment: Create your own function.

Comment: @AneesSaban test-for-draft_subform1 will always an array for me in the second array i.e. for $b

Comment: So you don't want a *merge*, you actually want the array in `$b["test-for-draft_subform1"]` to *throw away* the empty string you would get from `$a["test-for-draft_subform1"]`.

Comment: @Mangesh you can then call `array_filter` on both array before merging... check my answer

Comment: @Mangesh, if the blank would have been a *non-blank* string, would you expect the output to be any different? Is in that case the `[0]` entry desired?

Comment: Similarly, if the key would not exist at all in `$b`, do you want the key to be in the output (with the blank string as value)?

Comment: @DavidWinder thanks a lot..it works

Comment: @Mangesh if so please mark the answer as accepted so other may use it

Comment: @Mangesh, could you still answer the few questions I asked above?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array-filter](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and create your own function that does this recursivly as

```
function filter_rec($arr) {
    $arr = array_filter($arr);
    foreach($arr as &$elem)
        if (is_array($elem))
            $elem = filter_rec($elem);
    return $arr;
}
```

Call this function with your array

If all you want is to remove empty you can also do that with `array_filter` on the arrays before merging them

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of fixing this behavior (for this particular case) is to loop through the `$a` array and remove all values having an empty string before merging.

```
foreach($a as $k => $v) {
    if($v == '') {
        unset($a[$k]);
    }   
}
```

[Test it here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7382c30f76c8f1f83d994434174a67850f2e9050)

Answer (score 0):

When one of both values (that need to be merged) is not an array, you want only the other to go into the result, ignoring the non-array value.

There is no built-in function that would do that, so you would need to write your own:

```
function array_merge_recursive2($a, $b) {
    // If one is not an array, give precedence to the other
    if (!is_array($a)) return $b;
    if (!is_array($b)) return $a;
    $merged = [];
    foreach(array_merge($a, $b) as $k => $v) {
        $merged[$k] = !isset($a[$k]) ? $b[$k]
                      : (!isset($b[$k]) ? $a[$k]
                      : array_merge_recursive2($a[$k], $b[$k]));
    }
    return $merged;
}
```